# Error reason of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT for PlacesAPI

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api

I am working with PlacesAPI in my project. It worked perfectly till 5 to 6 times of request. However, suddenly after some request posting I am getting error of receiving OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. I tried to replace the api key by creating new one, but still it doesn't work for me. I even tried to create new project and this same process again but wont help me out. I want to know the reason why i am getting this error because they gives us 1000 request per 24 hours.

Comment: impossible to tell from the information provided.

Comment: you could check in the developer console. How many requests were hit and how many you have left.

Answer (score 1):

As @Engin Kurutepe said in [StackOverFlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831043/google-api-over-query-limit-issue-in-ios)

Make sure that you're not hitting the Google API too fast. They don't limit the total number of requests but the rate of requests. About 10 requests per second is more or less the fastest you're allowed to hit their APIs.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

it is 10,000 calls for places api but you will have to enable billing though it is free upto 200USD/month.

Also we have issues with places api not working today 12/05/2018 on all our apps.